# How to make the "-- more --" prompt more visible in irssi?

Tags: linux, colors, themes, irssi

I guess it's happened to most of us at least once: you flip to a channel, think "aw, how dull, nobody's said anything for hours..." — and then realize that it's because you forgot to scroll back down after reading an old conversation.  **facepalm**

Sure, irssi notifies you with a "-- more --" prompt on the right-hand side of the status bar (bottom right corner, circled in image below) when there are messages to the current channel that you haven't seen yet, because you're looking at the history.  The problem is that, at least on my default theme, this notice is shown in light gray on blue, and *really* easy to miss among all the other status noise:

[image: Screenshot of irssi with "-- more --" prompt circled]

I'd really like to make this notice, say, **bright red and bold** so that it would be more attention-catching.  Making it blink is strictly optional.

Irssi is pretty well configurable, so I assume that there's probably some way to do this.  The documentation is not the most approachable, though, and I clearly haven't found the right keywords to Google for.  Can anybody tell me what configuration setting I should be looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open your ~/.irssi/config file in your favourite text editor, and search for the key statusbar -> items -> more. It should read `more = "-- more --";`

modify it to read

```
more = "%_%R%F-- MORE --";
```

you can also change the displayed text. For more colours/attributes, check [the Formats page](https://github.com/shabble/irssi-docs/wiki/Formats#Local_Colours)

save the file, and in irssi run `/reload` to load it. (Not all terminal emulators support flashing)

Comment: Thanks, that was even easier than I expected. The red text on blue given by your example still didn't stand out *quite* as much as I wanted, but using the documentation you linked to, I ended up going with `"%_%1%y%F** MORE **"`, which gives a nice eye-catching yellow on red. Alas, my terminal doesn't seem to support the blink part. :(